# Average of two Newton's forward-difference polynomials gives Stirling formula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Let $x_{-n},x_{-n+1},...,x_{-1},x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{n-1},x_{n}$ be some real numbers such that $\forall k\in\{-n,-n+1,...,-1,0,1,...,n-1,n\}, x_k=x_0+k\times h$ for some $h>0$ (I.e. The points are equally spaced) and let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be some function.

(1) Find Newton's forward-difference formula for the interpolating polynomial of $f$ by using the points in the following order:

$x_0,x_{-1},x_1,x_{-2},x_2,...,x_n,x_{-n}$

(2) Find Newton's forward-difference formula for the interpolating polynomial of $f$ by using the points in the following order:

$x_0,x_{1},x_{-1},x_{2},x_{-2},...,x_{-n},x_n$

(3) Show that the **average** of the two formulas we got in (1) and (2) gives Stirling's formula:

$P(x)=f(x_0)+s\frac{\Delta f(x_{-1})+\Delta f(x_0)}{2}+\frac{s^2}{2}\Delta^2 f(x_{-1})+\frac{s(s^2-1)}{3!}\frac{\Delta^3 f(x_{-2})+\Delta^3 f(x_{-1})}{2}+\frac{s^2(s^2-1)}{4!}\Delta^4 f(x_{-2})+...+\frac{s(s^2-1)(s^2-2^2)...(s^2-(n-1)^2)}{3!}\frac{\Delta^{2n-1}f(x_{-n})+\Delta^{2n-1}f(x_{-n+1})}{2}+\frac{s^2(s^2-1)(s^2-2^2)...(s^2-(n-1)^2)}{(2n)!}\Delta^{2n} f(x_{-n})$

Where $s=\frac{x-x_0}{h}$ and $\Delta f(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)$ (The $\Delta$ is like the one in Aitken's $\Delta^2$ method).

---

Here's what I got:

(1) I was able to show that $P_1(x)=f[x_0]+\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} f[x_{I_1(0)},x_{I_1(1)},...,x_{I_1(i)}]\Pi_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_{I_1(j)})$

Where $f[x_{I_1(0)},x_{I_1(1)},...,x_{I_1(i)}]$ denotes *divided difference* and $I_1(i)=(-1)^{i}\lceil\frac{i}{2}\rceil$.

(2) I was able to show that $P_2(x)=f[x_0]+\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} f[x_{I_2(0)},x_{I_2(1)},...,x_{I_2(i)}]\Pi_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_{I_2(j)})$

Where $f[x_{I_2(0)},x_{I_2(1)},...,x_{I_2(i)}]$ denotes *divided difference* and $I_2(i)=(-1)^{(i+1)}\lceil\frac{i}{2}\rceil$.

(3) I've tried several times to show that the average of the two formulas I got in (1) and (2) gives Stirling's formula but I got bogged down in very complicated algebraic expressions and I wasn't able to proceed.

Thanks for any help.